# Prevent path autocompletion from using CDPATH in bash?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

On my Mac, bash (version 3.2.53(1)) autocompletes command-line arguments using files *only* in the current directory.

On a Linux machine at work, bash (version 4.1.2(1)) autocompletes command-line arguments using files from the current directory *and* parent directories.

For example, given the directory tree:

```
/home/pjl/
    bin/
    foo/
        book/
```

If on my Mac I do:

```
$ cd foo
$ cd b<TAB>
$ cd book
```

bash autocompletes *only* to `book`. However, when I'm on the Linux machine and do the exact same thing:

```
$ cd foo
$ cd b<TAB>
bin book
$ cd b
```

bash presents two choices: `book` from the current directory *and* `bin` from the parent directory.

How can make bash autocomplete *only* using the current directory (like it does on my Mac)?

On *both* machines, I do have `CDPATH` set to:

```
.:..:../..:../../..:../../../..:../../../../..:/home/pjl/src:/home/pjl
```

and if I unset `CDPATH` on the Linux machine, then bash autocompletes using *only* the current directory (which is what I want); hence I know the bash on Linux is using `CDPATH`.

But how can I keep `CDPATH` set (so `cd`'ing works as before), but *not* have bash use `CDPATH` when doing autocompletion?

---

An alternate acceptable behavior would be to have autocompletion *favor* the current directory and use `CDPATH` *if and only if* nothing in the current directory matches.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [CDPATH Bash completion in OSX](http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/cdpath-bash-completion-in-osx)

Comment: @Cyrus: no, it doesn't. I want to do the _opposite_ and make Linux behave like OS X (or bash 4.x behave like bash 3.x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be to use the following in your `~/.bashrc` as @Gilles suggested above (shorter version here):

```
_my_cd () { CDPATH= _cd "$@";}
```

A better way would be to check `CDPATH` if and only if no matches are found locally:

```
_my_cd () { CDPATH= _cd "$@"; if [ -z "$COMPREPLY" ]; then _cd "$@"; fi;}
```

This way you get the functionality of programmable completion without it being a nuisance. Do not forget

```
complete -F _my_cd cd
```

For some reason `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` has `-o nospace` for `cd` (even though `nospace` seems to be default), so you might as well have:

```
complete -F _my_cd -o nospace cd
```

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is your [bash_completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), not your bash version at all.

With [the head version from bash_completion repo](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/5ecb9d7e1372961f4f983b1fd0adaa273ac06bc4/bash_completion#L1670), `cd` auto completion include directories under `CDPATH`.

You can make change directly to your local `bash_completion`, but it's better to write your own `cd` auto completion.

---

If you want a global effect, create a file named `/etc/bash_completion.d/cd` with the following content:

```
_cd()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    _init_completion || return

    local IFS=$'\n' i

    compopt -o filenames

    local -r mark_dirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-directories && echo y)
    local -r mark_symdirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-symlinked-directories && echo y)

    _filedir -d

    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        i=${COMPREPLY[0]}
        if [[ "$i" == "$cur" && $i != "*/" ]]; then
            COMPREPLY[0]="${i}/"
        fi
    fi

    return 0
}
if shopt -q cdable_vars; then
    complete -v -F _cd -o nospace cd
else
    complete -F _cd -o nospace cd
fi
```

This version got all from the original, exclude the `CDPATH` part.

---

If you want to use only for your setting, you can edit `.bashrc` with the following:

```
_my_cd () {
  declare CDPATH=
  _cd "$@" 
}

complete -F _my_cd cd
```

---

There's some case made bash completion didn't work with `CDPATH` in your Mac OSX, your `bash_completion` is too old or you hadn't load it yet.

You can use `BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR` variable to set the location where `bash_completion` load your custom completion function, the default is `/etc/bash_completion.d`.

Comment: When I try to set `BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR`, bash complains that it's a readonly variable.

Comment: You must set it before you source bash _completion.

Comment: _I_ don't source `bash_completion`. The Linux machine is a shared machine, FYI, and I don't have super-user permissions.

Comment: You should check your `.bashrc`, `bash_completion` can be sourced from there. Otherwise, just paste the above code into your `.bashrc`.

Comment: `cd b`<TAB>`-bash: _init_completion: command not found`

Comment: Check if `/etc/bash_completion` existed then source it before the above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27200/discussion-between-paul-j-lucas-and-cuonglm).

Comment: Why modify a file in `/etc` rather than use `~/.bashrc`? Why not simply `_my_cd () { declare CDPATH=; _cd "$@"; }; complete -F _my_cd cd` ?

Comment: @Gilles: My bad, didn't think about this, only assume the OP want a global effect and have the root permission. Updated with yours, thanks!